# PHP: my regex code not work on local but on regex101 work fine

Tags: php, regex

I use regex101 for test my regex

This is my regex :

```
<a href="/name/nm0000130/\?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr8">(.*)</a>
```

And this is code :

```
<tr>
  <td class="name">
    <a href="/name/nm0000130/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr8"> Jamie Lee Curtis
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td class="credit">
    executive producer
  </td>
</tr>
```

This code work fine on regex101, but if i get data by `file_get_contents` and use this, my regex in php not work

I sure data load complete

My php code :

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt'.$tt.'/fullcredits', false, stream_context_create($contextOption));
preg_match_all('~<a href="/name/nm0000130/\?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr8">(.*)</a>~isU', $data, $return);
```

Other my regex code for this page work fine, but this is not work

My code;

```
$contextOption = array("ssl" => array(  "verify_peer" => false,
                                                "verify_peer_name" => false,
                                                "allow_self_signed" => true));

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502407/fullcredits', false, stream_context_create($contextOption));
preg_match_all('~<a href="/name/nm0000130/.ref_=ttfc_fc_cr8"(.*)</a>~isU', $data, $return);
```

Comment: I tried your code, it worked for me. [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/213b26b1e41114289d90bf405e834abecb003c82)

Comment: @Ibu Yes. in plaintext work fine. but after `file_get_contents` not work

Comment: @Ibu please check my question again. i added full code

Comment: there is no `/name/nm0000130/` on that page

Comment: when you say "it didn't work" what exactly does that mean?

Comment: you need a space there `/\?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr8"\s*>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse html [don't use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Instead use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or some other tool made for the job.

Here's a basic example of how you could approach the same thing using the [DOMXpath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
// get the html
$contextOption = ["ssl" => ["verify_peer" => false, "verify_peer_name" => false, "allow_self_signed" => true]];
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502407/fullcredits', false, stream_context_create($contextOption));

// load the html into DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// get anchor tag with href matching
$anchor = $xpath->query('//a[@href="/name/nm0000130/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1"]');

echo $anchor->item(0)->textContent;
```

**OUTPUT:**

> `Jamie Lee Curtis`